# Appcelerator iOS 12 Location

Tags: location, appcelerator, ios12

Are there new code changes to be made for iOS 12 when it comes to location services, as opposed to iOS 11?

I have the following code that works perfectly in iOS 11, but in iOS 12, even though it asks for the prompts as far as always/when in use, and I see the GPS icon, I get undefined on my e.coords.

```
var hasLocationPermission = Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS);


    if (hasLocationPermission) {
    //this just calls the function, but it the e.coords comes back as undefined in iOS 12, fine in iOS 11

        getLocation();
    }

function getLocation() {
    Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', function (e) {
        try {
            longitude = e.coords.longitude;
            latitude = e.coords.latitude;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err', err)
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the iOS 11+ `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in your plist, which became more important in iOS 12, because the prompt will suggest to use the less critical "when in use" permission if you do not include the above key. In addition, make sure to always first ask for the "when in use" permission and then upgrade to "always" later.

See the [Ti.Geolocation docs](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation) for details.